# How do I use Facebook's open graph tag 'product.group'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am having a hard time finding the answer to what seems like a simple question. Is the facebook open graph tag 'product.group' used for categories of products or variants of a single product?

I can not seem to find any live examples of this OG object either. Can anyone give me some direction or insight?

The closest I have come to an answer is the following but is just an example of the markup and the description is very vague.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product.group/

Any help would be super appreciated.